# mpdf prints only less than 450 records

Tags: php, zend-framework, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate pdf but mpdf works only if records are less than 450. If records exceeds 450 then i got an error

```
 Out of memory (allocated 1792802816) (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\..\mpdf\classes\cssmgr.php on line 17742
```

Please provide me a better solution. My code is here

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',360000);
set_time_limit(360000) ;
ignore_user_abort(true) ;
foreach($violations1 as $val)
        {   
            $exportpdf .= '<tr>';
                $exportpdf .= '<td  width="100" >'.$val['street_number'].'</td>';
                $exportpdf .= '<td  width="120" >'.$val['street_name'].'</td>';
                $exportpdf .= '<td  width="155" >'.$val['city'].'</td>';
                $exportpdf .= '<td  width="175"  >'.$val['zip'].'</td>';
                $exportpdf .= '<td  width="160" >'.$val['country'].'</td>';
            $exportpdf .= '</tr>';      
        }       
    $exportpdf .= '</table>';
$exportpdf = preg_replace('/>\s+</', "><", $exportpdf);
include("mpdf/mpdf.php");   
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4-L','','',32,25,34,18,16,13);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0; 
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('mpdf/mpdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->setFooter('Page {PAGENO}') ;
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<html><body>'.$exportpdf.'</body></html>');
$mpdf->Output('rec.pdf','D');
exit;
```

Comment: Please provide some code so that people can help you... you probably did something wrong, but it's hard to tell what if you're not showing code.

Comment: @Bartdude, yes you can see my code now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, i have found the solution, you will have to add these lines

```
$mpdf->cacheTables = true;
$mpdf->simpleTables=true;
$mpdf->packTableData=true;
```

and its working for me at least 5000 records

Answer (score 1):

You will have to increase the `memory_limit` in your php.ini

Comment: i have tried using `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` but it shows _Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\...\...\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 13347_

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that the errors in your question and comment have different line numbers, so try once more with some more memory and see what error comes.

Comment: I have change memory_limit from 256M to 1024M then it shows _Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in C:\...\..\mpdf\mpdf.php on line 13347_

Comment: Maybe, your HTML is too big. See these for help: http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=408 and http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=406

Answer (score 1):

On mpdf you have the option to disable "pretty table borders", a feature that increases dramatically the memory usage.

```
$mpdf->simpleTables = true;
```

However, I found out that sometimes this is not enough. What I do in this case is once I assigns all the html to a variable and then I set as false/null any other variable that I no longer need. For instance, in this case you have a data array $violations1 but after building the html and assigning it to $exportpdf, the $violations1 variable becomes pretty much useless.

There is another option:

```
$mpdf->packTableData = true;
```

I've tried that but with little success. If you have a SQL data object/array too big (specially working with ORM and a lot of records) or if you are using Smarty to render the ui, it works better to flush these big variables after building the html.

Of course, having more memory in the system is a good thing. But if you cannot add the `ini_set('memory_limit','256M')` to the system, using this little mpdf hacks does the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my story in case someone else falls on this result (`PHP 7.2.10`). I have ran into the same scenario when I started running some load tests for a project I am working on.

In my case I was unable to generate more than 51 PDF's before exhausting the `128 MB` of memory.

I was able to overcome the problem by explicitly invoking PHP's GC using `gc_collect_cycles()` after every iteration, with no apparent performance impact:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php

After adding the call to the aforementioned function, the script had already happily generated more than 2000 PDF's before I decided to stopped it.

The next thing I will do is to not call `gc_collect_cycles()` every iteration and instead grab some figures about the memory usage at runtime and trigger the GC in relation to that.

At the same time you should make sure the code does not *leak*, because in this case you would not be dealing with the cause, but just masking the effects.

Increasing the memory should only be looked at as a last resort, in my opinion as it may not fix the problem, but only enable you to generate more PDF's before running out of resources.